# Trouble using Math.max() in a For loop

Tags: javascript

I want to get the biggest number on each array looping `[0,1,2,3]` with `for`.

I am not managing to figure what to do in order to have the desired output.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     console.log(Math.max(...arr[i])) \\returns => 5, 27, 39, 1001
    }
  }

  console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

`console.log(Math.max(...arr[i]))` returns `5, 27, 39, 1001`. When I remove `console.log` and use a return at this line, in many different approaches, the iteration is not done. The loop stops and returns just the biggest number at `arr[0]` instead of looping completely.

The desired output is to get the biggest number of each array = `5, 27, 39, 1001`

Comment: What's the desired output / return value? The `[1000, 1001, 857, 1]` array? Its sum, highest value, or what?

Comment: hint: you can't return more than once from a function - use Array map function

Comment: I have just edited the post above. I want the result ```5, 27, 39, 1001``` After figuring this out I will push these values into a new array, or try to filter ```arr``` to get ```[5],[27],[39],[1001]```

Comment: @Alioshr Then `push` them into a new array instead of logging them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't return more than once from a function

Your code, if it returned in the body of the for loop, would return from the function in the first iteration

use Array map function

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    return arr.map(a => Math.max(...a))
  }

  console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        result.push(Math.max(...arr[i]));
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```